# HTML input align in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align all the inputs according to the image [image]. I tried to put the  `<center>` so that the div is in the center, but I have no idea how to align the elements according to the given image.

```html
<center>
    <div>
        <div>
            <center>
            Priority:
            <input  align="middle" type="radio" id="high" name="priority" value="High">
            High
            <input type="radio" id="medium" name="priority" value="Medium">
            Medium
            <input type="radio" id="low" name="priority" value="Low">
            Low
             </center>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">  
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <label for="appointment_date">Date: </label>
            <input type="date" id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date">

            <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
            <input type="time" id="start_time" name="start_time" />

            <label for="end_time">End Time</label>
            <input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="button" onclick="addAppointment()" value="Add Appointment" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50550511/6222075

Comment: center is deprecated brother !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it with flex-box:

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 6px 0;
   max-width: 600px;
   margin: auto;
   
  }

input[type="text"] {
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  Priority:
  <span><input align="middle" type="radio" id="high" name="priority" value="High"> High</span>
  <span><input type="radio" id="medium" name="priority" value="Medium"> Medium</span>
  <span><input type="radio" id="low" name="priority" value="Low"> Low</span>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <label for="appointment_date">Date: </label>
  <input type="date" id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date">

  <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="start_time" name="start_time" />

  <label for="end_time">End Time</label>
  <input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time" />
 </div>
 <center> <input type="button" onclick="addAppointment()" value="Add Appointment" />

 </center>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write CSS. Use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) to build this. Added a Sample code for this.

1. [Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) is not supported in HTML5 and deprecated.
2. Start writing custom CSS

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- first row -->
    <div class="row my-3">
      <div class="col-sm-3">Priority:</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input align="middle" type="radio" id="high" name="priority" value="High"> High
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" id="medium" name="priority" value="Medium"> Medium
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" id="low" name="priority" value="Low"> Low
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second row -->
    <div class="row my-3">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="subject">Subject: </label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject"></div>
    </div>

  <!-- 3rd row -->

  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <label for="appointment_date">Date: </label>
      <input type="date" id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
      <input type="time" id="start_time" name="start_time" /></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="end_time">End Time</label>
      <input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time" /></div>
  </div>
  <!-- 4th row -->

  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <input type="button" onclick="addAppointment()" value="Add Appointment" />
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <!-- container ends -->
```

Comment: is there any way without using any external CSS library like Bootstrap. I want to do it with simple CSS

Comment: You need to write custom CSS. Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549799/html-input-align-in-a-div#answer-50550028

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex for doing this.

Please see the [code pen created](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqvYYm)

```
#priotityContainer{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it i have used bootstarp for it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Vojtěch Matras">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" >Priority</div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-10" > <input type="radio" name="Priority" value="high">high<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Priority" value="medium"> medium<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Priority" value="low"> low</div>
   </div>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" >Subject</div>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-10" style="display: block"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" >Date:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" ><input type="date" id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" >Start time:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" ><input type="time" id="start_time" name="start_time" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" >End time:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-2" ><input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time"/></div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <center><input type="button" value="Add Appointment"></center>

</html>
```

you can check fiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/mgdzuod4/

Comment: @shubham johar is it wokring??